# What CSS selector do I need here?

Tags: css, apache-flex, flash, mxml, css-selectors

I'm trying to center the *title* text on my Alert control. I'm using the following CSS right now:

```
mx|Alert{
  text-align: center;
}
```

The problem is that the above code centers my alert content as well, not just the title text. What selector do I need to access just the title of the alert control?

**Edit:**

I'm using the 4.x SDK and Spark.

***Code:***

`Alert.Show();`

Comment: What version of the SDK are you using? 3.x or 4.x?  If the latter, are you using a spark or mx skin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `titleStyleName` to declare a CSS class that can be used to style the title, then add styles to that class:

```
mx|Alert {
    titleStyleName: 'alertTitle';
}

.alertTitle {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Should work for Spark if I'm not wrong.

Comment: +! but be sure to correct the style name.  There are no dashes in it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [titleStyleName](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/Alert.html?filter_flex=4.1&filter_flashplayer=10.1&filter_air=2#top).